# Unable to connect to Twitter API vi acurl

Tags: curl, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am testing with free twitter developer API, but getting following error:

> curl: (28) SSL/TLS connection timeout

The input in CMD is:

`curl --request GET "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=from:twitterdev" --header "Authorization: Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAF%2FPqgEAAAAAn2zBdGCHwsJNsG1qC22K1GTevZI%3DEhfMM1BDCI9byHyMM6wgReg0xXYkvt7ExUY7SnveQIBBmdM9zG"`

Expecting it to connect to twitter